# Controller unit tests using JUnit 5 in Spring Boot v3.0.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to write unit tests for the controller class using JUnit 5 in Spring Boot (v3.0.1). I am stuck with the below error. I have included the controller and the test classes for your review.

If I add a `@NoArgsConstructor`, the compiler complains that final fields are not initialized.

If I inject taskservice and taskmapper in addition to providing a default constructor, the test fails throwing the error - this.taskService is null.

Could anyone tell me which is the correct way to inject dependencies in the controller considering the testability.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

```
        org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ttk.taskitems.controller.TaskController]: No default constructor found

        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.instantiateIfNecessary(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.<init>(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:151)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:76)
        at com.ttk.taskitems.controller.TaskControllerUnitTests.setUp(TaskControllerUnitTests.java:59)
        .
        .
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ttk.taskitems.controller.TaskController.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
        ... 78 more
```

TaskController class

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/tasks", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class TaskController {

        private final TaskService taskService;
        private final TaskMapper map;

        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<TaskDto> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Optional<Task> item = taskService.findByTaskId(id);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(map.taskDto(item.get()));
        }
        }
    }
```

TaskControllerUnitTests class

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class TaskControllerUnitTests {


        @Mock
        private TaskService taskService;

        @InjectMocks
        private TaskControllerTaskController;

        @Mock
        private TaskMapper mapper;

        @Spy
        private Tasks task; //Test data builder 

        @SpyBean
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        private Task task;
        private TaskDto taskDto;
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        
        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(TaskController.class).build();
            task = Tasks.anItem(); // data builder
            TaskDto = Tasks.anItemDto(); // data builder
        }

        @Test
        void givenValidId_whenFindTaskById_thenReturnOK() throws Exception {
            Long id = 1L;
            when(taskService.findByTaskId(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(task));
            when(mapper.toDto(task)).thenReturn(taskDto);

            mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/tasks/{id}", id)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(taskDto)));
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to autowire those 2 beans:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/tasks", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  
    public class TaskController {

        @Autowired
        private final TaskService taskService;

        @Autowired
        private final TaskMapper map;

        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<TaskDto> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Optional<Task> item = taskService.findByTaskId(id);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(map.taskDto(item.get()));
        }
    }
```